# Parsing XML with vb.net 2008, detecting missing tag in node using XmlReader

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, xml-parsing

I am parsing an XML files, had no issues until I found a tag missing in a node

How Can I detect that missing tag?

Here is a sample for the XML

```
 <Line>
  <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
  <ItemType>C</ItemType>
  <CommentType>I</CommentType>
  <ItemDescription1>Data</ItemDescription1>
 </Line>
 <Line>
  <LineNumber>3</LineNumber>
  <ItemType>C</ItemType>
  <CommentType>I</CommentType>
 </Line>
```

Notice in the second node, there is no `<ItemDescription1>`

Here is some code.

```
Using reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(New StringReader(sFileContects))
Dim s As String = reader.ReadToNextSibling("ItemDescription1")
If reader.ReadToNextSibling("ItemDescription1") Then
    reader.ReadToFollowing("ItemDescription1")
    output.AppendLine(sLineType & " ItemDescription1: " + reader.ReadElementContentAsString())
End If
```

Comment: Consider using `XElement`, which is much easier to use.

Comment: How would you detect the missing tag in XElement?

Also, This is a big project and this is my only stumbling block

Comment: `If element.Element("ItemDescription1") Is Nothing`